# How to access localhost:1080 on Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, port, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to access localhost with specified port on my application on Cloud9 platform. I'm building a ruby on rails app, running a server with command below.

```
rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```

I have a special occasion where I need to access a different port (not localhost:3000). Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Cloud9 now has multiple external ports (released a few days ago but not yet documented). You can run a service on port 8081 or 8082 and it will be accessible by appending the relevant port to your preview url (e.g. http://project-user.c9.io:8081). Only http works for now, https will be available soon.

Comment: ran the server like the following, rails s -b $IP -p 8081

Comment: and tried to access through http://project-user.c9.io:8081/ but it redirects to https and I get a "No application seems to be running here" page.

Comment: Can you send an email to support@c9.io with details and we'll help you figure out what's happening.