# How to access localhost on Cloud9 with Socket.IO

Tags: socket.io, localhost, cloud9-ide

I'm following [this tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and using Cloud9, but when I run `node index.js` I can't seem to find it.

I've looked at these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990818/how-to-connect-to-the-process-running-on-localhost-that-is-inside-of-cloud9-se) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535529/how-to-access-localhost1080-on-cloud9), but neither seem to work for me. Am I just following their instructions wrong?

Comment: Please give more detailed explanation. Things such as: `what was the full error printed`, `what was the expected outcome`, `what was the actual outcome`. Also post any screenshots and code snippets you think are relevant.

Comment: Also note that Cloud9 only forwards servers listening on `0.0.0:8080` (and also ports `8081` and `8082`). In the above examples, the code is using 3000 which might be the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the server to listen on 8080 (as Mutahhir [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990818/how-to-connect-to-the-process-running-on-localhost-that-is-inside-of-cloud9-se#comment45358002_28508813)) and then point my web browser to `http://workspacename.username.c9.io` (as Kendell [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16184766/5049813) on another question). Make sure that its an http connection, not an https connection.

To set the server to listen on 8080, you just change `3000` to `8080` in the index.js file.

Then, the "Hello World" shows up as it's supposed to.